# Al ejecutar un SELECT por rango de fechas, no muestra la fecha actual

Tags: mysql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta por fechas en mi base de datos, pero se comporta de manera extraña

esta es la consulta :

```
SELECT DISTINCT empresa,order_rec,id_orden_pass,estado_rec,id_recolector_2,
 horario_rec, identificacion,direccion, serie,tarjeta, equipo, nombre_cliente, 
 cable_hdmi, cable_av,fuente, control_1,adicional, otrosaccesorios, codigo_postal
  from express where  
  estado_rec IN('A-CONFIRMAR','RECUPERADO',
      'PACTADO','RECHAZADA',
      'EN-USO','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO','NO-EXISTE-NUMERO','NO-RESPONDE','TIEMPO-ESPERA','SE-MUDO',
      'YA-RETIRADO','ZONA-PELIGROSA','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO','N/TEL-EQUIVOCADO',
        'NO-COINCIDE-SERIE') and
id_orden_pass IS NOT NULL AND horario_rec >='2020-07-20' AND horario_rec <='2020-07-28'
  UNION SELECT empresa,order_rec,id_orden_pass,
  estado_rec,id_recolector_2, horario_rec, identificacion,direccion, 
serie, tarjeta, equipo, nombre_cliente, cable_hdmi, cable_av,
fuente, control_1,adicional,otrosaccesorios, codigo_postal FROM autorizar where
 estado_rec IN('A-CONFIRMAR','RECUPERADO',
      'PACTADO','RECHAZADA',
      'EN-USO','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO','NO-EXISTE-NUMERO','NO-RESPONDE','TIEMPO-ESPERA','SE-MUDO',
      'YA-RETIRADO','ZONA-PELIGROSA','NO-TUVO-EQUIPO','N/TEL-EQUIVOCADO','NO-COINCIDE-SERIE') and
id_orden_pass IS NOT NULL AND  horario_rec >='2020-07-20' AND horario_rec <='2020-07-28'
 ORDER BY horario_rec desc;
```

Lo raro es que solamente trae datos desde la fecha de inicio hasta un dia antes de la fecha final
es decir, trae solamente registros que tengan fecha de 2020-07-202 hasta 2020-07-27.

Uso mysql y el campo `horario_rec` es de tipo `datetime`, ya le puse `varchar` y tampoco.
Lo ideal es que traiga todos los datos si es mayor o igual que `>=` o menos o igual que `<=`. ¿Por qué puede estar sucediendo esto?

Y en las dos tablas que consulto tengo muchos registros con fecha `2020-07-28`.

Comment: Y cumplen las otras condiciones del where? deberias mostrar los datos que tenes asi se puede verificar eso...

Comment: has comprobado que no tengas los campos con fecha y hora?. Muchas veces el problema esta con las horas que mira solo hasta el dia final a las 0:00:00 y por eso no suele traer datos de ese dia

Comment: ahi modifique la pregunta y le agregue una foto

Comment: Si estás usando datetime, tal y como dice @JoseJavierSegura, seguro te está poniendo una hora por defecto, que parece ser 00:00:00. Si necesitas guardar fecha hora, entonces haz la comparación incluyendo la hora (23:59:59 ?)

Answer (score -1):

El problema con los campos DATETIME, esta con la fecha. Por defecto la hora que te coge el sistema es la 0:00:00, por lo que los registros del último día no suelen salir.

Una forma de optimizar la consulta es usar la condición BETWEEN .... AND ...., que mejora algo el rendimiento. Así tu sentencia quedaría de esta manera

```
horario_rec BETWEEN '2020-07-20' AND '2020-07-28'
```

Aunque este cambio, tampoco solucionará tu consulta.
Para solucionarlo deberas hacer un CAST sobre el campo, quedandote la consulta de esta manera

```
horario_rec BETWEEN CAST('2020-07-20' AS DATE) AND CAST('2020-07-28' AS DATE);
```

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que usar BETWEEN mejora el rendimiento? Y por ahí derecho, ¿añadir el cast a DATE no degrada el rendimiento? Si ese campo no está indexado, va a hacer cast de TODO en esa columna

Comment: Al menos hasta 5.x, BETWEEN es mero syntax sugar (sólo reordena cosas pero el optimizador lo trata igual): [documentación MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between). `If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type.`. Yo me quedaría con tu sugerencia en los comentarios y no con la respuesta que pones.